# Costly HASH MATCH Aggregate

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a view,which is slow when i query a simple select statement with a `where` clause.The where clause column is indexed(`Non-clustered` index)
Here is the view and the plan.
[execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkJcNqd2m)

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CurrentIncidentStatus]
AS
SELECT [incidentDetails].[IncidentStatus], [incidentDetails].[IncidentStatus_FieldValue], [incidentDetails].[IncidentStatus_Description], Report.Id ReportId, Form.Id FormId
FROM
[dbo].[IncidentDetailsPage_Incident] incidentDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[IncidentDetailsPages] detailsPage WITH (NOLOCK)
ON incidentDetails.PageId = detailsPage.Id
INNER JOIN Form WITH (NOLOCK)
ON detailsPage.FormId = Form.Id
INNER JOIN Report WITH (NOLOCK)
ON Form.ReportId = Report.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Supplements supplement WITH (NOLOCK)
ON detailsPage.Id = supplement.PageId
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ReportId, Max(FormNumber) RecentFormNumber FROM
    (
        SELECT Report.Id ReportId, FormId, COALESCE(SupplementNumber, '0000') formNumber
        FROM dbo.IncidentDetailsPages detailPage WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Form WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.FormId = Form.Id
        INNER JOIN Report WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON Form.ReportId = Report.Id 
        INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Incident incident WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.Id = incident.PageId 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Supplements supplement WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.Id = supplement.PageId) FormNumbers
        GROUP By ReportId) RecentForm
ON Report.Id = RecentForm.ReportId AND
RecentForm.RecentFormNumber = COALESCE(supplement.SupplementNumber, '0000')
GO
```

I analyzed the plan in `Sentry Plan explorer` and learned that the `HASH JOIN Aggregate` is the costly operation in the plan.
I am trying to avoid/remove that `HASH JOIN` someway.?
If any of you have experienced similar situation please give some suggestion.

Additional Info:

The plan says Hash key is built on Table `Report` and column `Id`.
In-fact the `Id`column is the `primary key` in the `Report` table ,so a `clustered index` is present also a `Non-clustered` index is created for Id column.
Still why Hashing is required for Report.Id?

Here is the screenshot of the HASH MATCH Aggregate operation.

[image]

Info:
When i select TOP 100 or 1000 it doesn't show HASH MATCH (Aggregate).

Thanks

Comment: I ran the query in SSMS and then copied that XML into SentryOne Plan Explorer.

Comment: Try running the query from Plan Explorer. You get a bunch of additional metrics for free and when the query runs long enough we will show you the **actual** distribution of costs (when we just have the XML, we can only show you the estimate, which will always stay the same no matter what happens at runtime). Sometimes this will show that the operator that was *estimated* to be most costly wasn't the problem in the end.

Comment: I tried to connect to the db server,but the security settings is not allowing me to connect to the db server.I have to contact someone and try.

Comment: Your query is doing a five table join and then inner joining onto the same five table join with a group by and `max`. You could simplify things a lot by adding `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ReportId ORDER BY  SupplementNumber DESC)` to the five table join and then filtering where that equals `1` without any need to join back onto itself

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but I need more room than a comment allows, so...

First, you should consolidate your query - you have an unnecessary step in it:

```
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Report.Id ReportId, Max(COALESCE(SupplementNumber, '0000')) RecentFormNumber
    FROM dbo.IncidentDetailsPages detailPage WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Form WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.FormId = Form.Id
    INNER JOIN Report WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON Form.ReportId = Report.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Incident incident WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.Id = incident.PageId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Supplements supplement WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.Id = supplement.PageId
    GROUP By Report.Id
    ) RecentForm
```

Second, you should get rid of the redundant use of the Report table, ending up with a query like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CurrentIncidentStatus]
AS
SELECT [incidentDetails].[IncidentStatus], 
    [incidentDetails].[IncidentStatus_FieldValue], 
    [incidentDetails].[IncidentStatus_Description], 
    Report.Id ReportId, 
    Form.Id FormId
FROM [dbo].[IncidentDetailsPage_Incident] incidentDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[IncidentDetailsPages] detailsPage WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON incidentDetails.PageId = detailsPage.Id
INNER JOIN Form WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON detailsPage.FormId = Form.Id
INNER JOIN Report WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON Form.ReportId = Report.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Supplements supplement WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON detailsPage.Id = supplement.PageId
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Report.Id ReportId, Max(COALESCE(SupplementNumber, '0000')) RecentFormNumber
    FROM dbo.IncidentDetailsPages detailPage WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN Form WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.FormId = Form.Id
    INNER JOIN Report WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON Form.ReportId = Report.Id 
    INNER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Incident incident WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.Id = incident.PageId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.IncidentDetailsPage_Supplements supplement WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON detailPage.Id = supplement.PageId
    GROUP By Report.Id
    ) RecentForm
    ON Form.ReportId = RecentForm.ReportId 
    AND RecentForm.RecentFormNumber = COALESCE(supplement.SupplementNumber, '0000')
GO
```

With these simplifications, please check the query plan again.

Comment: I did consolidate the query like you mentioned,but the plan still has HASH MATCH (Aggregate).I know that HASH MATCH is done on Report.Id but i don't understand why it is doing HASH Match even though there is an index for Id.

Comment: The HASH MATCH aggregate is building a table where you have the key, and the result of an aggregate for the key - in this case, the Report.Id and the MAX() aggregate.  Because you're INNER JOINing to a subquery, it seems to be getting the results for the subquery, performing the aggregation for it, then joining the results.  I'd try changing it to a CROSS APPLY, which means the subquery runs filtered for each report id you're querying - rather than running as a separate query independent before the join.